# Will the search time decrease if we erase some elements in c++ unordered_map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, unordered-map

I encountered a algorithm problem in a online judge system. I used the unordered_map to serve as the dictionary. However, if I erase some visited elements in the unordered_map, my program will be accepted, otherwise not. The size of the unordered_map has nothing to do with the number of searches. So, my questions is will the search time decrease if we erase some elements in c++ unordered_map? I think the unordered_map is a hash_table, the number of elements inside shouldn't have anything to do with the search performance.

Comment: Search time increases with the number of elements in the unordered_map, specially if you need to dynamically allocate extra memory to fit all those unneeded elements.

Comment: I believe the `unordered_map` is a hash-table of buckets. So the average search time is **constant** but the worst case is **linear**. Check: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/find/

Comment: If your hash function is collision prone, erasing elements may speed further operations on the same bucket.  If you're erasing some before adding others, your overall hash table size may be kept smaller, reducing resizing overheads and cache faults during lookups.  The `unordered_map` API exposes enough of the internals for you to code a histogram of the elements per bucket - you could find out yourself if there's something bodgy going on given your actual data, algo and hash function.